# Will Objective-C runtime release retained associative references for user?

Tags: objective-c, reference, associative

When some codes like this:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject (
  obj,
  &key,
  val,
  OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN
);
```

Do I need to call related

```
objc_setAssociatedObject (
  obj,
  &key,
  nil,
  OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN
);
```

to release the retained value? Does Objective-C runtime auto release the associative references in `dealloc` or somewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Associated objects will be released when the parent object is deallocated. See the documentation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120818164935/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html), specifically this example:

> At point 1, the string `overview` is still valid because the `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` policy specifies that the array retains the associated object. When the array is deallocated, however (at point 2), `overview` is released and so in this case also deallocated.