# Garbage in (strong) Objective C property inside a delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm new to Objective C so I kindly ask to forgive my ignorance.
I'm trying to get [this code](https://github.com/mschulkind/cordova-true-native-ios/blob/master/Example/Classes/UIWebViewScriptDebugDelegate.m) to work, to no avail.

In my header file, I have declared a property:

```
@interface UIWebViewScriptDebugDelegate : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *sourceIDMap;

@end
```

In my code file, I synthesize and initialize it:

```
@implementation UIWebViewScriptDebugDelegate

@synthesize sourceIDMap = sourceIDMap_;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.sourceIDMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}
```

It works just fine—if I insert an `NSLog` call, I see that `self.sourceIDMap` is indeed a dictionary.
However, by the moment another method wants to access the property, it looks like `NSMutableDictionary` is gone.

```
- (void) webView:(WebView*)webView
  didParseSource:(NSString*)source
  baseLineNumber:(unsigned int)baseLineNumber
         fromURL:(NSURL*)url
        sourceId:(int)sourceID
     forWebFrame:(WebFrame*)webFrame
{
    // ...

    NSLog(@"Look what we got here:");
    NSLog(@"%@", self.sourceIDMap);
}
```

Sometimes it is a `DOMCSSStyleDeclaration`, sometimes it is a `DOMHTMLHeadElement`:

```
360 MyApp[49113:1507] Look what we got here:
360 MyApp[49113:1507] <WebScriptObjectPrivate: 0x14540d20>
361 MyApp[49113:1507] -[DOMCSSStyleDeclaration sourceIDMap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc32e550
361 MyApp[49113:1507] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didParseSource:baseLineNumber:fromURL:sourceId:forWebFrame: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[DOMCSSStyleDeclaration sourceIDMap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc32e550
367 MyApp[49113:1507] Look what we got here:
368 MyApp[49113:1507] <WebScriptObjectPrivate: 0x14540ee0>
369 MyApp[49113:1507] -[DOMHTMLHeadElement sourceIDMap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145ec820
369 MyApp[49113:1507] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didParseSource:baseLineNumber:fromURL:sourceId:forWebFrame: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[DOMHTMLHeadElement sourceIDMap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145ec820
```

Where's the `NSMutableDictionary`? Isn't it supposed to be retained?

#### Update

If this helps, the code is compiled into a static library with ARC enabled that I'm calling from MonoTouch.

Comment: can u post the code where u acutally put data in the NSMutableArray?

Comment: @MrBr: The point is: I don't. I removed all code that accesses the dictionary except for `init` where it is created, and `didParseSource` where I test for it.

Comment: Are you sure your UIWebViewScriptDebugDelegate is properly retained? (Try with NSZombies)

Comment: I'd also assume that this has nothing to do with the array itself but with the objects you append to it.

Comment: @fabrice: I'm not. I assumed the code would not get called at all if the delegate was not retained. I don't know what `NSZombies` are so give me some time to google it and follow up. Thanks.

Comment: @MrBr: The objects are just `NSDictionary`es, and again—it fails even if I append nothing at all.

Comment: You are using a class variable inside a delegate method which probably was defined as an informal protocol! Your class is using a delegate method from webscriptdebugdelegate but your class is not saying anywhere that it has to conform to that protocol.

Comment: @fabrice: I made it work by inserting a call to `objc_setAssociatedObject` with `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` when setting the delegate. I'm not sure if this is a right approach, and I also don't know how to release i yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked wjen I added

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(sender,
    @"ScriptDebuggerDelegate", delegate, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN
    );
```

before calling `setScriptDebugDelegate:` on `sender` in `didClearWindowObject`.

Kudos go to [fabrice truillot de chambrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541523/garbage-in-strong-objective-c-property#comment15261140_11541523) for the tip.
(It seems like I [don't even need to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122600/will-objective-c-runtime-release-retained-associative-references-for-user) `release` it myself.)